# Why doesn't the search for an element that does not contain a value work in xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

A piece of html page that I have:

```html
<html lang="ru">
    <body>
        <form name="substitutionFM" class="form-data" onsubmit="return !1">
            <input name="message" id="message" type="hidden" value="error.password.invalid">
        </form>
        <div _ngcontent-c17="" class="content">
            <input _ngcontent-c15="" automation-id="bui-primitive-textfield__native-input" class="input bui-autofill ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted" aria-placeholder="" id="bui_01584205838454" type="text" tabindex="0" inputmode="numeric" x-inputmode="numeric" aria-describedby="bui_01584205838454_described-by" style="padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My xpath that I am trying to find the elements I want:

```
.//input/@*[(contains(., "otp") or contains(., "ode") or contains(., "assword") or contains(., "numeric")) and not(contains(., "hidden"))]/..
```

As you can see, I don't want to find hidden elements, but that doesn't work, and both elements are in the browser and in the selenium, but I only need the second one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
'//input[@*[contains(., "otp") or contains(., "ode") or contains(., "assword") or contains(., "numeric")] and not(@*[contains(., "hidden")])]'
```